# Android Development: Implementing MCQ quiz app

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, sqlite

I am a beginner in android app development and was trying to build a simple MCQ quiz app.

What I did was make a two dimensional array and stored the questions, possible answers and the correct solution in it.

A sample from the table can be seen in this image:

[image]

So I named my array database. The code for creating this array called database[][] is below:

```
    database = new String[][]{
            {"Before marking the finishing line on a running track, a groundsman measures out its 100 m length. Which instrument is the most appropriate for this purpose?",
                    "measuring tape","metre rule","30 cm ruler","micrometer", "A"},
            {"A car of mass 1500 kg travels along a horizontal road. It accelerates steadily from 10 m / s to 25 m / s in 5.0 s. What is the force needed to produce this acceleration?",
                    "300N","500N","4500N","D.7500N", "C"},
            {"A lorry of mass 10 000 kg takes 5000 kg of sand to the top of a hill 50 m high, unloads the sand and then returns to the bottom of the hill. The gravitational field strength is 10 N / kg. What is the overall gain in potential energy?",
                    "250 000 J","750 000 J","2 500 000 J","D.7 500 000J", "C"},     
            {"A liquid-in-glass thermometer contains mercury. Which physical property of the mercury varies with temperature, enabling the thermometer to operate?",
                        "mass","melting point","resistance","volume", "D"}, 
            {"Thermal energy of 12 000 J is supplied to a 2.0 kg mass of copper. The specific heat capacity of copper is 400 J / (kg °C). What is the rise in temperature?",
                        "15 Degree C","30 Degree C","60 Degree C","100 Degree C", "A"}, 
    };
```

So each row is basically a new question with its own set of possible answers.

As for the interface, there is a textview that shows the question. There are four buttons which show each of the answers. You click on a button to answer. Then the next question is showed.

```
    textviewQuestion.setText(database[x][y]);
    buttonA.setText("A. " + database[x][1]);
    buttonB.setText("B. " + database[x][2]);
    buttonC.setText("C. " + database[x][3]);
    buttonD.setText("D. " + database[x][4]);
```

**Now my question is, if I want to make this app more versatile is it better to use other ways to implement the questions? I mean maybe I can store the questions in a text file? Or should I use SQLite? I don't know the pros and cons and basically what are the limitations?**

**I have the questions in pdf format, so can I use that to somehow link those questions directly from the pdf to the app?**

**Also I want to be able to ask questions which include some images. How to achieve that? Please help me out by pointing me to some good resources. Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code is help for opening pdf in your app

```
File pdfFile = new File(path); 
        if(pdfFile.exists()) 
        {

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            try
            {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(uractivity.this, "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any ideas on how to use database?